# Show that there exists c such that $f(c)=c^2$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[0,1] \rightarrow  [0,1]$ be a continuous function. Show that there exists c in $[0,1]$ such that $f(c)=c^2$

Comment: Hint: apply the intermediate value theorem to $g(x) = f(x) - x^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the function $g(x)=f(x)-x^2$.  Evaluate at $0$ and $1$ and use the intermediate value theorem.